# error opening image php

Tags: php, image, jpeg, fopen

I've just changed hosting and domain. With the former domain I had a script that worked well. Instead now the same script does not want to work anymore. I have modified nothing. It's a php page that takes a jpg image and adds some little images and so on.
All the files that the php page requires are in the same folder.
This is the php page code (webcam.php) http://www.meteoacquaviva.it/webcam/webcam.php

```
<? include("counter.php"); ?>
<?php
$nome_immagine="../webcam/webcam.jpg";  // file contenente l'immagine base
$nome_testo="../webcam/uniques.txt";   // file contenente i dati meteo per le scritte sulla barra
$fp = fopen($nome_testo,"r")
   or die("impossibile aprire il file uniques.txt.");
$testo_sinistra=fgets($fp,120);   // nella prima riga la scritta allineata a sinistra
$testo_destra=fgets($fp,80);   // nella seconda riga la scritta allineata a destra
if ( $testo_destra = "data" )
   { 
   setlocale(LC_TIME,"it_IT");
   $testo_destra=strftime ("%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", filemtime($nome_immagine)); 
   }
fclose($fp);
header("Content-type: image/png");
$im  = imagecreatefromjpeg($nome_immagine);
$colore_barra = imagecolorallocate($im, 1, 0, 128);  // colore della barra formato RGB
$colore_testo  = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255); // idem per testo
$x=imagesx($im);
$y=imagesy($im);
$font = "../webcam/VeraBd.ttf";
$size = 8;       // dimensione del testo
$altezza_barra = 20;      // dimensione della barra
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, $y-$altezza_barra, $x-1, $y-1, $colore_barra);
$bbox = imagettfbbox ($size, 0, $font, $testo_sinistra);
$dy   = (($bbox[1] - $bbox[7]) / 2);
imagettftext($im, $size, 0, 5, $y-($altezza_barra / 2) + $dy - 1, $colore_testo, $font, $testo_sinistra);
$bbox = imagettfbbox ($size, 0, $font, $testo_destra);
$dx   = ($bbox[2] - $bbox[0]);
imagettftext($im, $size, 0, $x-5-$dx, $y-($altezza_barra / 2) + $dy - 1, $colore_testo, $font, $testo_destra);
$info = getimagesize($nome_immagine);                  //carica immagine                
$logo = imagecreatefrompng("../webcam/stemma2.png") ;          //carica 1° logo - h/= cartella - sacile.png = nome del file e estensione.png
//$logo2 = imagecreatefrompng("bstemma.png") ;   //carica 2° logo - h/= cartella - mnw.png = nome del file e estensione.png
$logo3 = imagecreatefrompng("../webcam/logobig.png") ;   //carica 3° logo - h/= cartella - logo_M3V.png = nome del file e estensione.png

imagecopy($im, $logo, 5, $info[1] -115, 0, 0, 71,93); //(156,64=dimensione 1°logo)posizione 1°logo(1400=x,-1100=y)
imagecopy($im, $logo2, 700, $info[1]-65, 0, 0, 150,38); //(150,38=dimensione 2°logo)posizione 2°logo(1400=x,-800=y)
imagecopy($im, $logo3, 865, $info[1]-680, 0, 0, 150,26); //(150,53=dimensione 3°logo)posizione 3°logo(1400=x,-800=y)
imagejpeg($im,"",85);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

This is the image that as to be taken
http://www.meteoacquaviva.it/webcam/webcam.jpg

Comment: Does your new host allow your php scripts to write to the file system? What errors show up on the screen or in the error logs?

Comment: How can I verify that?
When I open the php page
http://www.meteoacquaviva.it/webcam/webcam.php
I have:
"the image cannot be displayed because it contains errors"

Comment: I bet your php script is outputting errors.  comment out the `header("Content-type: image/png");` line and you may get some more information.

Comment: Thanks Robert for your support! I have this: 
Warning: imagecopy() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in /web/htdocs/www.meteoacquaviva.it/home/webcam/webcam.php on line 37

and

Warning: imagejpeg(): Filename cannot be empty in /web/htdocs/www.meteoacquaviva.it/home/webcam/webcam.php on line 39